# cronjob remote php file, on which server executed?

Tags: php, curl, cron

I'm running a php script with cUrl every 5 minutes. Now I would like to run this script from a remote server.

for example on server 1 the script is in public_html/cron/cron.php
on server 2 a cronjob is setup every 5 minutes.

when the cronjob is running which ip adress will be registered, from server 1 or server 2?

Comment: The script on server 1 will have the IP address of server 2 in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the IP address will be the one from the server that initiates the request, so in your case it will be server 2.